# What is the best way to allocate an array when reading big files

Tags: c, memory-management

I have a file around 100 MB, which needs to be processed.

After I get the dimensions of that file (h & w), I should read the data into an array. I am thinking of several ways how to do that:

**1. Static (automatic)**

```
int matrix[h][w];
```

**2. Dynamic**

```
// similar to above, but using malloc
```

I am worried about the limitations (and freeing the memory).

Also, would a static array be freed whet it's scope is over?

Comment: This is totally up to your design. If you are worried about limitations - first understand them and see if they are actually limiting you.

Comment: I already did that and found out that by using static way, it can handle a file up to 8 MB, which is not what I expected.

Comment: and now that I'm thinking, I really can't use `by chunks` solution. So, is there any difference betweem static and dynamic?

Comment: You want to tell me that you can't statically allocate 100MB? That sounds suspicious. Are you sure you tried to  *statically* allocate it? Or you did it on stack (inside `main`)?

Comment: If 8 Mb is enough to exhaust your memory, you have not told you enough to understand why...

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yeah, that's not clear to me. I am working only inside `main` and the variable is inside an if condition. Btw,  would a static array be freed when it's scope is over?

Comment: Option 1 isn't an option if `h` and `w` are not known at run time.  Even if the 'static' referred to isn't `static`, if you have 100 MB data, then the array is going to be too big for the stack.  So, dynamic it has to be — `malloc()` rules.  If you can process the data piecemeal, without needing it all in memory, then do so.  If you need it all in memory, allocate the memory with `malloc()` or one of its colleagues (dynamically allocated memory).

Comment: A third option is to memory-map the file. On many OSes, this could be much more efficient, especially if you only need to read a small portion of the file. The glib library does I/O that way.

Comment: @DonJoe You should familiarize yourself with storage classes in C. `static` means that it is static that's it. It is there always until the program is finished.`Static` variables are defined in global scope or with a `static` keyword. Otherwise they will be `automatic` instead and consume stack space.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for the answers .Now it's more clear to me. Maybe someone should write the answer talking about what I called static, which goes into stack (limited) and dynamic (malloc) which goes into heap.

Comment: The `static` and `auto` storage classes do not necessarily mean a variable is stored on the stack or not stored on the stack. It’s totally plausible, for example, that an implementation could allocate a very large object with automatic storage on the heap, keep a pointer to it on the stack, and free it on return (as if it were a reference to a `std::unique_ptr` from C++). Or it might allocate static variables on the stack before calling `main()`.

Comment: @Davislor So you're saying that my first option could also be on heap? Then, why would my program run out of memory? Or does it depend on the compiler / OS ?

Comment: Why do you want load the whole file? I remember that is possible to map and use a file as it was in memory. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html

Comment: `int (*matrix)[h][w] = malloc(sizeof *matrix);` is a way to "allocate an array when reading big files".  Yet using a _big array_ is not the best way to handle this.

Comment: "What is the best" depends on coding goals including how `matrix` is used and manipulated.  Without that info, this question remains unclear.

Comment: ^^ what @chux says.  With some data/requirements, it would be best to load a series of 1MB buffers and submit them to another thread or pool for processing.  Without much more detail, the question is unclear.

Comment: @DonJoe It’s up to the compiler.

Comment: However, a `static` array will never be freed. On a modern OS, its memory should get paged out to the swap file if it’s not used for a while.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, the solution is using dynamic allocation.

It seems that `int matrix[h][w];` puts data in stack, which is limited (small), whereas using `malloc()` puts data in heap, which is as big as 75% of the virtual memory (in Linux).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the application, but one good approach most of the time is to map the file to memory.  On a modern OS, this will return a pointer to the file contents and make a file on a hard drive work like the swap file: the application will just see its contents as memory, but the OS will only load the pages into memory when (it expects that) you access them.  This could save you a lot of time and complication if you only need to read a small part of the file.

This is how [the `glib` library does file I/O](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-File-Utilities.html#g-file-get-contents), or it is available through `mmap()` on Unix/Linux and a different set of functions in the Windows API.